# Alpine Linux – NFS: Cannot properly export a mount point

Tags: mount, nfs, alpine-linux

## The Config

I am running Version 3.13.0 on a Raspberry Pi 4. `/etc/export/` looks like this:

```
/export  *(fsid=root,sync,crossmnt,nohide,no_subtree_check)

# regular directory that can be mounted correctly by client
/export/test  *(sync,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)

# mount point of /dev/sdb1; cannot be mounted by client
/export/drive  *(sync,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
```

Initially, I restricted NFS to version 4 and 4.1 in `/etc/conf.d/nfs`, but I restored everything to default after discovering my problem.

## The Problem

I tried mounting a btrfs formatted drive and an ExFat formatted drive to `/export/drive`. Both worked as expected on the host system.

Mounting on the client system worked correctly both for `/export/test` and `/export`, but mounting `/export/drive` just froze the prompt: No error message, nothing. I waited for several minutes.

When mounting `/export`, trying to view either the content of `/export` or the `drive` sub-directory via `ls` also froze the prompt, as described above. Listing the content of `/export/test` worked, though.

I did not specify any options when mounting: `mount 10.0.0.20:/drive /mnt/drive`

Running `exportfs -arv` doesn’t report any errors.

The server’s log doesn’t show anything unusual, the (failed) mount attempt of `/export/drive` produced the same message as successfully mounting `/export/test`.

## What I tried

I tried running `rcpdebug -m nfsd -s all` (as suggested by [this short guide](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-nfs-debug-logging-using-rpcdebug/)) resulting in this error:

```
/proc/sys/sunrpc/nfsd_debug: No such file or directory
```

I also tried adding the `mp` option, which should only export the specified path if is a mount point. I tried it for both `/export/test` and `drive`: Mounting `/test` has successfully been prevented; mounting `/drive` was not different from before.

Finally, I replicated the setup on the client system and reversed roles: Setting up my Gentoo system with the same configuration as described above, accessing `/export/drive` *from* the Alpine system — **it worked!**

### Update

I also checked `nfsstat`, where everything looks normal: zero *badcalls, badclnt, badauth*.

Running `nfsstat -m` on the client did not print anything after (unsuccessfully) mounting `/drive` — it gave a result with `/test`, though.

So I thought that maybe the client could be the problem. With `mount localhost:/drive /mnt/drive` on both my Alpine and Gentoo system the results did not change: Mounting results in a freeze whenever Alpine acts as server.

Finally, I tried forcing NFS 3 with `-o nfsvers=3`, leading to the same results as usual (`/test` works, `/drive` freezes).

## Questions

- What can I try to make this work on Alpine?
- Are there any mount options I should consider?
- How can I make use of `rcpdebug`?
- Is there another way to increase verbosity and gain more information?
- Which kind of information can I provide to ease helping me?
- Where else can I ask for support?

---

**Any** hint is highly appreciated! Thank you!

I initially asked this question on [r/AlpineLinux](https://www.reddit.com/r/AlpineLinux/comments/l5obfp/nfs_exporting_mounted_fs_results_in_freeze_on/).

---

## Edit

I did not encounter any problems testing the same setup with different operating systems (Gentoo, Raspberry Pi OS Lite). I believe it is a bug with Alpine Linux; I opened an issue: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12360

Comment: What exactly is mounted on the server at `/export/drive`?  I assume it's a filesystem on `/dev/sdb1`, but you need to provide that detail both here and in the bug report you filed.

Comment: Yes, you assumed right, but the issue has been resolved. Anyway, thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsid` was missing. `/etc/exports` now looks like this:

```
/export *(fsid=root,sync,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
/export/test *(sync,no_subtree_check)
/export/drive *(sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=1)
```

For further context and explanations, check out the [now resolved issue](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12360#note_139389).